# How can I fix this access violation writing location?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, 32bit-64bit, memory-access

I am porting from 32 to 64 bit and the project is so far that it is compiling. But I get exceptions when I try to start the program. I already changed `Set/GetWindowLong with Set/GetWindowLongPtr` anf checked with the /Wp64 for warnings but there are too many (like 3000).

This is the block of code where the exception appears:

```
FARPROC old_evhndl = (FARPROC)obj->old_eventhandler(); //ide shows me here the address of old_evhndl
if (!old_evhndl || !IsWindow (hwnd))
    return 0;

if ((msg==WM_MOUSEWHEEL)&&scroll_handl)
    return 0;

LRESULT lRes = CallWindowProc(old_evhndl, hwnd, msg, (WPARAM)wParam,(LPARAM) lParam); //exception points here | ide shows me here the address of old_evhndl
return lRes;
```

The exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9F241D7E6 (user32.dll) in filetool.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000BFEFD0B0.
```

The high 32 bits of that 64-bit address are all zero AND it's obviously invalid as it's showing up in an access violation. So it's obviously been truncated.

Realistically, the only way this happens is casting a pointer to a 32-bit integer type and back.

I traced it back but could not find anything suspicious. Maybe it can't handle the conversion from old_eventhandler to FARPROC. old_eventhandler has the type void*.

The address the ide is pointing me for old_evhndl is `ntdll.dll!0x00007FF9F 403BE60`. I see a similarity to this address `0x00007FF9F E24D7E6`. You can also see it from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60pF2.jpg

Comment: Not much we can do without a [mre]

Comment: What's the type `old_eventhandler()` return? Is it `int (FAR WINAPI * FARPROC) ()` or is it `LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC) (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)`? Is `STRICT` defined or not?

Comment: 3000 warnings is not 'too many' if there are 3000 problems with the code, turn the warnings on and work though them. If you are a professional that's what I would expect you to do. If this is a personal project then I guess you've learned the lesson to try and write better quality code in the first place.

Comment: When we switched from x86 to x64 we got also a huge amount of warnings. Most of them because we were under the _wrong_ impression that `sizeof (unsigned)` is always `sizeof(size_t)`. (It's not as I learnt the hard way.) Suppressing such warnings hides possible wrong or undefined behavior. I see no other solution than to work them through (or at least have an eye on them how critical they might be).

Comment: STRICT is not defined and the definition of old_eventhandler() is like this: virtual void* old_eventhandler()    { return NULL; }

Comment: If `obj->old_eventhandler()` returns `NULL` then `old_evhndl` should be `(FARPROC)nullptr`. So, the next `if (!old_evhndl` should bail out. That's confusing...

Comment: 3000 warnings doesn't mean 3000 things to fix. Problems in headers multiply, as the compiler will warn every time it's included.

Comment: @Scheff: The giveaway there is `virtual`. The actual problem is in an override. But that just gets us back to the first comment: show us the **actual** code.